# How to solve the issue of "Error archiving file : Access is denied" while deploying Lambda function using terraform?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip, terraform

I want to deploy an AWS lambda function using Terraform. For that I have created my project directory with the name of **lambda terraform**, which has the following files and folders inside it -
[image]

File **hello.js** contains the following code -

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

Then inside **IAM** folder, I have created two files named **lambda_assume_role_policy.json** and **lambda_policy.json** by following the terraform documentation.

Then I have created another file named **iam-lambda.tf** which has the following code -

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name   = "lambda_policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id

  policy = file("IAM/lambda_policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name               = "lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = file("IAM/lambda_assume_role_policy.json")
}
```

After that I have created **lambda.tf** and it's code is as follows -

```
data "archive_file" "hello" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "hello.js"
  output_path = "hello.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = "hello.zip"
  function_name = "hello"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler       = "hello.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x" 
}
```

At last I have created the file **provider.tf** -

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
}
```

I opened the Git bash terminal and navigated to the project directory and ran `terraform init`, which downloaded all the plugins. Then I ran `terraform apply -auto-approve` and got the following **error** -
[image]

Please help me out of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was coming across the same issue in our CI/CD. I think the reason this is happening is because the created zip does not have the correct permissions. Lambda needs 755 for the zip, but the data block zip that gets created does not have this.

Creating a zip file in the /tmp folder worked for me as the tmp folder has higher permissions of 777 and the created zip from the data "archive_file" will also have 777 permissions.

Hope this helps anyone looking.

```
locals {
  zip_file = "/tmp/some_zip.zip"
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambda.py"
  output_path = local.zip_file
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  function_name    = "${var.function_name}"
  filename         = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"
```

Answer (score -2):

In the `aws_lambda_function` resource, you have to specify output of the `archive_file` as the filename:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
    filename = data.archive_file.hello.output_path
    hash = data.archive_file.hello.output_base64sha256
}
```